# How to get a random value from a string array without repetition?

Tags: android, arrays, string, random, non-repetitive

How to get a random value from a string array in android without repetition?

I have array in `String.xml` file as below -

```
    <string-array name="msg">
    <item>Cow</item>
    <item>Pig</item>
    <item>Bird</item>
    <item>Sheep</item>
</string-array>
```

I am selecting random string by using following code -

```
String[] array = Objects.requireNonNull(context).getResources().getStringArray(R.array.msg);
String Msg = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks is advance...!

Comment: Do you have a loop or something?

Comment: no i don't have any loop

Comment: I don't know why people will edit question unnecessarily... I can understand if anything is wrong/missing then they can happily edit but just removing one word dosent make any sense...Work less people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

```
array = Objects.requireNonNull(context).getResources().getStringArray(R.array.msg);
    //String msg = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];

    LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (String i : array)
        myList.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(myList);

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
       String msg=myList.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: Wow...Working...Thanks...! But it is just combination @Mike & Gowtham code Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

Can you just do something like this:

```
Collections.shuffle(copyOfArray);
```

Then loop through that?

```
for (int i = 0; i < copyOfArray.size(); i++) {
  println(copyOfArray.get(i))
}
```

Comment: `shuffle
(java.util.List<?>)
in Collections cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String[])`

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution,

```
LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();

  String[] words = { "Cow", "Pig", "Bird", "Sheep" };
     for (String i : words) 
       myList.add(i);
       Collections.shuffle(myList);
```

Then,

```
sampleText.setText(myList.pollLast());
```

`pollLast()` in LinkedList will retrieves and removes the last element of this list, or returns null if this list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
int max = array.length() - 1;
int min = 0;
String Msg = array[new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min];
```

Answer (score 0):

- First convert your String resource array to ArrayList
- Fill value from current ArrayList to HashSet and convert that HashSet to newly ArrayList
- Now shuffle that new ArrayList